# How to access a local rails website using virtualbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualbox

I'm working on a local Rails website, and I'd like to access to it from my visrtualbox machine running winXP

From my Ubuntu machine, I use my browser to open http://www.myapp.local:3000 
How can I access it from Virtualbox?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your xp machine, open up your hosts file at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts in a local text editor like notepad or whatever is on there.

Then add a line like this:

10.70.30.31        www.myapp.local

Where 10.70.30.31 is the IP address of your Ubuntu machine.

Save the hosts file. Then restart whatever browser you're using on the XP box. Make sure you close all of the browser windows you have open as well because your browser will cache your hosts file until you properly restart it.

Once you've opened a new browser window you should be able to access your rails site from the same address you use on your Ubuntu machine.

http://www.myapp.local:3000